# ASP.Net - How to download a shortcut forcing the user to use Edge

Tags: asp.net, shortcut

We have an ASP.Net application that allows a user to download a customized shortcut to our application.  Please consider the following code...

```
    Response.Clear();
    Response.ContentType = "application/internet-shortcut";
    Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=OurApp.url");
    Response.Write("[InternetShortcut]\r\n");
    Response.Write("URL=" + "http://google.com" + "\r\n");
    Response.End();
```

I've replaced the customized URL with google to improve readability...

When served that code presents the user with a "SaveAs" dialog and writes a normal Internet Shortcut to a location of his/her liking.  When doubled-clicked the default browser (typically IE) correctly navigates to our application.

Question: How can we modify that code to force the shortcut to use Microsoft Edge?  (Without changing the default browser on the client.)

Please do not suggest changing the shortcut manually once it's downloaded/saved - it needs to be seamless to the user.

Thanks!

--- Curt

Comment: You cannot force the browser. It opens using the default browser specified in the OS. And mobiles do not have Edge anyway.

Comment: You can make a shortcut like the one shown here: https://superuser.com/a/1168450/718250, a shortcut to explorer.exe that has arguments of "microsoft-edge:http://www.example.com"